# How do I copy one Data Extension to another using AMPScript or Server-Side JavaScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

how To copy data one Data extension to another Data Extension by using Amp Script or Server side java script.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<script runat=server>

   Platform.Load("Core","1");
   var Extension1 = DataExtension.Init("DE11");
   var newList = DataExtension.Init("DE33")
   Write(Stringify(Extension1.lenght));
   var Extension2 = Extension1.Rows.Retrieve();
   Write(Stringify(Extension2.lenght));

   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var sub = data[i];
      newList.Rows.Add({Email:sub.Email,Lastname:sub.Lastname, Firstname:sub.Firstname});
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Please explain your use case properly, put the details what have you tried so far, so that some one who have idea can help you better.

Comment: Please read articles on how to ask questions on the forum.

Comment: This doesn't move or copy anything.  Is this the correct code block?

Comment: @Nachiket Deshpande
please Read My Quetion Clearly First And Understand My Quetion .I Already Asked Quetion ?. No one  is Not Update Code For Me After Iam Getting The Answer My Own Coding .  that one its Working Clearly Same As  my requirement .pLease Check And Let me Know ..

Comment: How much have you read about the [AMPScript](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/) and [SSJS](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/platform_server_side_javascript_functions/) API functions?

Answer (score 2):

**Assumptions**

1. You can write T-SQL queries
2. Data Extension 1 = A. Data Extension 2 = B.

**Instructions:**

1. Go to Automation Studio
2. Click on activities
3. Select "Create Activity" in the upper right corner.
4. Select "SQL Query"
5. Type in the Query in the screen below.
6. Validate your query. If it is correct, you should see a a green tab as seen below.

[image]

Select B as your target Data Extension.
Select which data action you want. You can either choose to append, overwrite or update the data extension.
Save it and you can run the automation.
If successful, all the data from A will be copied to B.

Comment: This isn't SSJS or AMPScript, which is what the OP asked.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs the question has been edited since I answered it. I suspect this is a dud user as the same question appears multiple times . The same user group has recently done this again for a recent question indicating same person multiple accounts

Comment: Sorry about that.  You're right. I noticed his other questions. :|